# Switch between two DataReaders

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
private void supplBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
      sqlcon.Open();
   }
   cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Supplier_info where Supplier_name = '" + supplBox.Text + "'", sqlcon);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      suppNum.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(0));
   }
   reader.Close();
   sqlcon.Close();
   barCode1.Focus();
}
private void suppNum_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
      sqlcon.Open();
   }
   cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Supplier_info where Supplier_id = '" + suppNum.Text + "'", sqlcon);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      supplBox.Text = reader.GetString(1);
   }
   reader.Close();
   sqlcon.Close();
   barCode1.Focus();
}
```

When I switch between the supplBox and suppNum I get this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

If I add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to my connection I get this error:

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Help please

Comment: Connections are cheap. Create them when you need them and close/dispose once you have what you need. Do not share connections across multiple methods/calls, it is not worth the hassle.

Comment: using (SqlConnection sqlcon= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ // your code}

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using ADO.NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: thank you all but i need to correct my code so can anyone write the correct code so i can easily catch my fault?

Comment: @bommelding You are right. The top most duplicate is now.

Comment: YES, i have tried the @5740382 code and it worked perfect, thank you so much